# Get changed unsaved property value of a node in content tab, after clicking save button and before saving the changes. Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

**Update:**

I want to get a node's property value that has been changed after clicking save button and before saving the changes programmatically, on content tab in BackOffice.

The node could contain many properties. When the save button is clicked, I want to first get the new changed value for the node's properties. I think Umbraco should have APIs to get those in server side.

Any idea would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please find my update. I can provide more information if required.

Answer (score 1):

You want to wire into the Document.BeforeSave method in an IApplicationEventHandler class. Like so (assuming you're changing bodyText from "apple" to "orange"):

```
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web;
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Web;


namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1 : IApplicationEventHandler
    {
        public void OnApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplication httpApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            Document.BeforeSave += new Document.SaveEventHandler(Document_BeforeSave);
            Document.AfterSave += new Document.SaveEventHandler(Document_AfterSave);
        }

        void Document_BeforeSave(Document sender, umbraco.cms.businesslogic.SaveEventArgs e)
        {
            // your code goes here!
            sender.getProperty("bodyText").Value // returns apple
        }

        void Document_AfterSave(Document sender, umbraco.cms.businesslogic.SaveEventArgs e)
        {
            // your code goes here!
            sender.getProperty("bodyText").Value // returns orange
        }

        public void OnApplicationStarting(UmbracoApplication httpApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            // unused
        }

        public void OnApplicationInitialized(UmbracoApplication httpApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            // unused
        }

    }
}
```

I tested this in Umbraco 4.11

Cheers

Jonathan

Comment: I tried that. But the state of sender in the Document_BeforeSave is Not the value that is changed and not saved. For example, if I chanaged document A's content from apple to orange and click save button, the sender returns apple not orange.

Comment: In AfterSave event you will get "orange" in `sender.getProperty("bodyText").Value` (replace "bodyText" with whatever property you're after)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use a jquery event handler, that is targeted at the field in the umbraco admin you want to check for changes.  This example will work by finding the label of the umbraco field you want to monitor and then adding a jquery event handler that will fire when the field that is the sibling to the label is changed - this example will work for any changes to the 'Name' field that is on every node's 'properties' tab.  Different field types will hold the value differently, so $(this).val() should usually work for most - but not all field types.

Drop this into the end of \umbraco\editcontent.aspx

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("div.propertyItemheader:contains('Name') + div.propertyItemContent").keyup(function () {
                alert("field changed");
            });

        });
</script>
```

Comment: The node could contain many properties. Ideally, I want the logic in server side.

Comment: Doing client side work here is really not within best practice for Umbraco which does expose these events and properties server side.